# yeoman angular-ui-grid ui-grid angular version conflict between 1.2.28 and 1.3.8

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm putting together my first angular site and decided it is probably best I try to use yeoman before I get too deep into this. I can't figure out how to make everything work together.

I created an app with yeoman and when prompted and here are the options I choose:

```
yo angular myapp

Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? (Y/n) y
Would you like to include Bootstrap? (Y/n) y
Would you like to use the Sass version of Bootstrap? (Y/n) y

? Which modules would you like to include? (Press <space> to select)
>(*) angular-animate.js
 ( ) angular-aria.js
 (*) angular-cookies.js
 (*) angular-resource.js
 ( ) angular-messages.js
 (*) angular-route.js
 (*) angular-sanitize.js
 (*) angular-touch.js
```

At this point I have a functioning site.

Then I installed ui-grid using bower and this is where I run into problems.

```
bower install angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18

bower angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18           cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#3.0.0-RC.18
bower angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18         validate 3.0.0-RC.18 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#3.0.0-RC.18
bower angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18           cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#3.0.0-RC.18
bower angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18         validate 3.0.0-RC.18 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#3.0.0-RC.18
bower angular#^1.3.0                        cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.8
bower angular#^1.3.0                      validate 1.3.8 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.3.0
bower angular#1.3.8                         cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.8
bower angular#1.3.8                       validate 1.3.8 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.8
bower angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18          install angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18
bower angular#^1.3.0                       install angular#1.3.8
bower angular#~1.2.16                       cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#~1.2.16                     validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.16

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#~1.2.16 which resolved to 1.2.28 and is required by angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18
    2) angular#^1.3.0 which resolved to 1.3.8 and is required by officemanager
    3) angular#1.3.8 which resolved to 1.3.8 and is required by angular-animate#1.3.8Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer::
angular-ui-grid#3.0.0-RC.18 bower_components\angular-ui-grid
└── angular#1.3.8
```

Here is where I am lost. yeoman installed what appears to be a newer version of angular, but ui-grid appears to require a version that isn't supported by the modules in #3.

I tried option #1, site fails to work because the scripts in #3 fail.
I tried option #2/#3 and site works, but can't get grid to load.

I originally created a project outside of yeoman until I realized it is probably valuable to use such a tool.

Any help would be greatly appreciate!

Here is my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "officemanager",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.2.16",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-resource": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-route": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-touch": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-ui-grid": "3.0.0-RC.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and now have it working. I did the following, but I am not savvy enough to know if all steps are required. I am passing it along in case it helps or in case you have figured out a better way and can let me know.

1. Ran: bower install angular-ui-grid, and somewhere in the mix of trying to get it working, I also did: bower install angular-ui-grid --save-dev.
2. Manually updated index.html (from the yeoman angular-fullstack scaffolded app) with the css (head) and js (body) files in the right (bower-related) places, but then when I bounced grunt serve they were gone, so I put those lines outside of the bower-maintained areas -- obviously not the right solution.
3. Downloaded the zip of the most recent release candidate version from this page https://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid
4. Copied and replaced the version installed with bower with the files downloaded in the zip file.
5. Added 'ui.grid' to the list of dependencies in the client-side app.js
6. Added code like the sample from http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro into the respective files in a new yo-scaffolded route

And hot diggity dog -- it finally worked!